# Visualising a stream of emotions

Tags: visualization, sentiment-analysis

I have a stream of emotions (from some audio recordings) extracted by a speech emotion recogniser.  My questions now are how to best display these emotions to the end users?

- What is the best way to visualise this stream of emotions?
- Is there any tool/library/package/software that I can use a stream of ekman emotions (e.g. happy->surprise->sad->...) as input and get some visualisation as output?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an Alluvial Diagram (Sankey Diagram). You can actually show multiple stages between emotions. So while if you google Sankey you will likely mainly see one two stage demonstrations...that is from A to B, you can easily code it to show from A to B to C, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have one package for visualization and sentimental analysis together.

I think you can use 'TextBlob' Python package for the same. It is widely used for sentimental analysis. This package gives the Polarity measurement within a range and you can convert this range to 'happy, sad or neutral'

After this you can use seaborn library to create visualization on using **hue** parameter as **sentiments**

Comment: hi thanks. I have already a stream of emotions. I just need a way for visualization.

Comment: what type of visualization you are looking? You can use seaborn library for various types of visualizations or plots